# How to remove an appearance from a content-type?

Tags: magento2, page-builder

How can I remove an appearance from a default content-type? Is it possible?

I'd like to remove the appearance "grid" from the products content-type, since our custom theme does not support the grid.

Creating a `products.xml` and removing it from the appearances node does not work because magento merges it with the original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options for the appearances are managed via DI. In `pagebuilder_products_form.xml` the options provider is defined as `AppearanceSourceProducts`:

```
<field name="appearance" formElement="select" sortOrder="10" component="Magento_PageBuilder/js/form/element/dependent-visual-select">
    <formElements>
        <select>
            <settings>
                <options class="AppearanceSourceProducts" />
            </settings>
        </select>
    </formElements>
...
```

And in the `adminhtml/di.xml` it is defined like this:

```
    <virtualType name="AppearanceSourceProducts" type="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Source\VisualSelect">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="optionsSize" xsi:type="string">large</argument>
            <argument name="optionsData" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">grid</item>
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Grid</item>
                    <item name="icon" xsi:type="string">Magento_PageBuilder::css/images/content-type/products/appearance/grid.svg</item>
                </item>
                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">carousel</item>
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Carousel</item>
                    <item name="icon" xsi:type="string">Magento_PageBuilder::css/images/content-type/products/appearance/carousel.svg</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

It is possible to overwrite the original by declaring a custom `AppearanceSourceProductsCustom` and omitting the grid item, then setting a preference for the original `AppearanceSourceProducts`:

```
    <preference for="AppearanceSourceProducts" type="AppearanceSourceProductsCustom" />
    <virtualType name="AppearanceSourceProductsCustom" type="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Source\VisualSelect">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="optionsSize" xsi:type="string">large</argument>
            <argument name="optionsData" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">carousel</item>
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Carousel</item>
                    <item name="icon" xsi:type="string">Magento_PageBuilder::css/images/content-type/products/appearance/carousel.svg</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

Instead of overwriting `AppearanceSourceProductsCustom` via preference you can extend the `pagebuilder_products_form.xml` and set the custom class:

```
<field name="appearance">
    <formElements>
        <select>
            <settings>
                <options class="AppearanceSourceProductsCustom" />
            </settings>
        </select>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

To remove it from the default javascript config it is important to overwrite the `pagebuilder_products_carousel_form.xml` and the `pagebuilder_products_form.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd" extends="pagebuilder_base_form">
    <fieldset name="appearance_fieldset">
        <field name="appearance">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">carousel</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Then at last edit the `products.xml` content-type declaration and set the default there as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_PageBuilder:etc/content_type.xsd">
    <type name="products">
        <appearances>
            <appearance name="carousel"
                        default="true">
            </appearance>
            <appearance name="grid"
                        default="false">
            </appearance>
        </appearances>
    </type>
</config>
```

Now the grid option for the appearance is fully removed and only carousel is used and available in the page builder.

Answer (score 0):

To remove an appearance from a default content-type in Magento, you can use a plugin or observer to modify the layout update before it is rendered.

1. Create a new module with a custom plugin or observer that listens for the ***layout_load_before*** event.
2. In the plugin/observer method, use the layout object to remove the unwanted appearance node.
3. Clear the cache and check that the appearance is no longer present on the frontend.

```
class RemoveAppearance
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getData('layout');
        $layout->unsetElement('products.grid');
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a theme to override the layout file where the appearance is defined. This way, you can simply remove it from your custom theme's layout file, and it will take precedence over the default one.

Keep in mind that you need to be careful when using these methods as it will affect other places where the same layout is being used.